# MS Azure - Bad Request 400

Tags: c#, azure, azure-mobile-services, bad-request

I keep getting a bad request error every time I run this line of code:

```
List<Account> accounts = await App.accountTable.Where(account => account.EmailAddress == email).ToListAsync();
```

Here is the error message:

```
A first chance exception of type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceInvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceInvalidOperationException: The request could not be completed.  (Bad Request)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceHttpClient.<ThrowInvalidResponse>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceHttpClient.<SendRequestAsync>d__1d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceHttpClient.<RequestAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceTable.<ReadAsync>d__b.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceTable.<ReadAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Query.MobileServiceTableQueryProvider.<Execute>d__8`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Query.MobileServiceTableQueryProvider.<Execute>d__3`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceTableQuery`1.<ToListAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at eventsphere.Utilities.ValidationUtility.<CheckEmailExistsError>d__2.MoveNext()
```

However I have another line which is basically the same and it works fine:

```
List<Account> accounts = await App.accountTable.Where(account => account.Username == username).ToListAsync();
```

I am literally clueless as to why one line would give me an error and the other wouldn't since all that has changed is the property of the Account table I am querying.

Account Table Structure: (Won't let me post an image because I haven't enough reputation)

```
CREATE TABLE [eventsphere].[Accounts] (
    [Id]           NVARCHAR (128)     DEFAULT (newid()) NOT NULL,
    [AccountId]    INT                IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Username]     NVARCHAR (MAX)     NULL,
    [EmailAddress] NVARCHAR (MAX)     NULL,
    [Password]     NVARCHAR (MAX)     NULL,
    [IsBusiness]   BIT                NOT NULL,
    [User_Id]      NVARCHAR (128)     NULL,
    [Business_Id]  NVARCHAR (128)     NULL,
    [Version]      ROWVERSION         NOT NULL,
    [CreatedAt]    DATETIMEOFFSET (7) DEFAULT (sysutcdatetime()) NOT NULL,
    [UpdatedAt]    DATETIMEOFFSET (7) NULL,
    [Deleted]      BIT                NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_eventsphere.Accounts] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_eventsphere.Accounts_eventsphere.Businesses_Business_Id] FOREIGN KEY ([Business_Id]) REFERENCES [eventsphere].[Businesses] ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_eventsphere.Accounts_eventsphere.Users_User_Id] FOREIGN KEY ([User_Id]) REFERENCES [eventsphere].[Users] ([Id])
);
```

Any input would be appreciated! Thanks in advance :)

Comment: can you check if your table has the emailaddress column? also, post your table structure in the question.

Comment: Edited my post so that the Accounts table structure is included

Comment: In the MobileServiceInvalidOperationException that you catch there is a property called `Response`, which contains the response from the service. Can you look at the response content to see if it has any information about why the server considered the request to be bad?

Comment: Hi, here is the response message it isn't useful at all: 
{StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Pragma: no-cache
  X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcVXNlcnNcR3JhaGFtXERlc2t0b3BcUmVwb3NpdG9yeVxEaXNzZXJ0YXRpb25cdHJ1bmtccHJvamVjdFxldmVudHNwaGVyZV9tdWx0aVxldmVudHNwaGVyZVNlcnZpY2VcdGFibGVzXEFjY291bnQ=?=
  Cache-Control: no-cache
  Date: Sun, 25 Jan 2015 18:43:08 GMT
  Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
  Content-Length: 2389
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
  Expires: 0
}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does your client-side EmailAddress property look like? It is getting lowercased at some point -- do you have any attributes on it in your client model?

The reason that 'Username' and 'username' both work is because the server allows both upper-and lower-case with the first letter of properties. For example, 'emailAddress' should work.

Comment: Hi, we figured out the issue turned out the Web Api was out of sync with the tables hence the bad request. Silly mistake on our part never even thought about it (I am new to Azure). Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

(Can't comment until I have 10 reputation so I'm posting this as an answer..)

Here is the query request that's generated and sent to the local copy of our database:

```
http://localhost:59737/tables/Account?$filter=(emailaddress%20eq%20%27email%40test.com%27)
```

which returns this object (I think the "message" property is all that's important):

```
{"message":"The query specified in the URI is not valid. Could not find a property named 'emailaddress' on type 'eventsphereService.DataObjects.Account'.","exceptionMessage":"Could not find a property named 'emailaddress' on type 'eventsphereService.DataObjects.Account'.","exceptionType":"Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataException","stackTrace":"   at Microsoft.Data.OData.Query.EndPathBinder.GeneratePropertyAccessQueryForOpenType(EndPathToken endPathToken, SingleValueNode parentNode)\r\n   at Microsoft.Data.OData.Query.EndPathBinder.BindEndPath(EndPathToken endPathToken, BindingState state)\r\n   at Microsoft.Data.OData.Query.MetadataBinder.BindEndPath(EndPathToken endPathToken)\r\n   at Microsoft.Data.OData.Query.MetadataBinder.Bind(QueryToken token)\r\n   at Microsoft.Data.OData.Query.BinaryOperatorBinder.GetOperandFromToken(BinaryOperatorKind operatorKind, QueryToken queryToken)\r\n   at Microsoft.Data.OData.Query.BinaryOperatorBinder.BindBinaryOperator(BinaryOperatorToken binaryOperatorToken)\r\n   at Microsoft.Data.OData.Query.MetadataBinder.BindBinaryOperator(BinaryOperatorToken binaryOperatorToken)\r\n   at Microsoft.Data.OData.Query.MetadataBinder.Bind(QueryToken token)\r\n   at Microsoft.Data.OData.Query.FilterBinder.BindFilter(QueryToken filter)\r\n   at Microsoft.Data.OData.Query.ODataUriParser.ParseFilterImplementation(String filter, IEdmType elementType, IEdmEntitySet entitySet)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.OData.Query.FilterQueryOption.get_FilterClause()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.OData.Query.Validators.FilterQueryValidator.Validate(FilterQueryOption filterQueryOption, ODataValidationSettings settings)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.OData.Query.FilterQueryOption.Validate(ODataValidationSettings validationSettings)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.OData.Query.Validators.ODataQueryValidator.Validate(ODataQueryOptions options, ODataValidationSettings validationSettings)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.OData.Query.ODataQueryOptions.Validate(ODataValidationSettings validationSettings)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.OData.EnableQueryAttribute.ValidateQuery(HttpRequestMessage request, ODataQueryOptions queryOptions)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.OData.EnableQueryAttribute.ExecuteQuery(Object response, HttpRequestMessage request, HttpActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.OData.EnableQueryAttribute.OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)"}
```

however when modified (by us, in the browser) as follows:

```
http://localhost:59737/tables/Account?$filter=(EmailAddress%20eq%20%27email%40test.com%27)
```

it returns some data.

When querying the Username field both "Username" and "username" returns data.

The Account DataObject is defined as:

```
public class Account : EntityData
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int AccountId { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public bool IsBusiness { get; set; }

    public string User_Id { get; set; }
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    [ForeignKey("User_Id")]
    [Association("UserIdAssociation", "UserId", "Id")]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    public string Business_Id { get; set; }
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    [ForeignKey("Business_Id")]
    [Association("BusinessIdAssociation", "BusinessId", "Id")]
    public virtual Business Business { get; set; }
}
```