# Sql Database retrieving data to UWP

Tags: c#, sql, database, uwp, azure-sql-database

I have my database connected to UWP.

I have this code that works and pulls up all the data that don't have a null name.

```
 private async Task GetStory()
        {

            MobileServiceInvalidOperationException exception = null;

            try
            {
                // This code gets the entries in the list view by querying the stories table.
                items = await storyTable
                    .Where(todoItem => todoItem.Name != null)
                    .ToCollectionAsync();
            }
            catch (MobileServiceInvalidOperationException e)
            {
                exception = e;
            }

            if (exception != null)
            {
                await new MessageDialog(exception.Message, "Error loading items").ShowAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                ListViewItems.ItemsSource = items;
            }
        }
```

What I want is to load the data if the story is true or false.. on my table I have a column that is bool named isTrue and I set the value of each story to true of false. I am trying to get the true stories to show but the exception pops up.
Below is the code that doesn't work.. I just changed the .name != null to .isTrue !=false I also tried .isTrue == true, but nothing seems to work..

```
 private async Task GetStory()
        {

            MobileServiceInvalidOperationException exception = null;

            try
            {
                // This code gets the entries in the list view by querying the stories table.
                items = await storyTable
                    .Where(todoItem => todoItem.isTrue != false)
                    .ToCollectionAsync();
            }
            catch (MobileServiceInvalidOperationException e)
            {
                exception = e;
            }

            if (exception != null)
            {
                await new MessageDialog(exception.Message, "Error loading items").ShowAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                ListViewItems.ItemsSource = items;
            }
        }
```

Can anybody help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: So what is the exception message you are getting?

Comment: Error loading items.. its coded to show this when an exception shows.

Comment: The `exception.Message` part...

Comment: {"The request could not be completed.  (Bad Request)"}

Comment: Check this question, it might be related.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28132371/ms-azure-bad-request-400